# Apex code to know if an ChildRelationship is in my package

Tags: apex, managed-package, isv, schema

I am working out of a managed package and want to find out what lookups are created by customers of my package. So fields that are unpackage.

```
for(ChildRelationship rel : myType.getDescribe().getChildRelationships()) {
    if(isNotInMyPackage(rel) {
        ...
    }
}
```

How would I implement `isNotInMyPackage(ChildRelationship rel)`?

Comment: User created lookups in subscriber org would not have a namespace in `rel.getField()` and `rel.getRelationshipName()`, with that information you could match the SObject (`getChildSObject()`) to narrow down the result and find appropriate lookup.